# Simple example of Twitter "POST statuses/update_with_media" with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, jsonp

I'm trying to set up an ajax request to post a twitter status with an image. I've tried using type:"POST" (corss domain issues) and dataType:"jsonp" fomats (400 bad request).

I'm new to the Twitter API and they don't really have a lot of examples.